# How not to transform notice into ErrorException in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, jenkins, phpunit

Symfony2 seems to encapsulate all notice/warning into ErrorExceptions. Which is a nice behavior during development but this cause some problem with unit testing.

I launch unit tests with Jenkins, and some classes throw notices.
Theses notices are transformed into exception... Which crash the unit test.

I already try with phpunit specific argument but it doesn't change ( `convertWarningsToExceptions = false`, etc. ).

So, how can I change this default behavior ?

Comment: Why do you prefer to have warnings instead of exceptions?

Comment: Having PHP code throwing notices is not a good signal. If you really want to suppress all PHP warnings and notices try to use the `@` operator. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: @ONe I can use convertNoticesToExceptions = false in phpunit so it wont mark the test as failed.

Comment: If a notice is thrown it means something went not as expected which should let the test fail or you should expect it in which case you can set the `@expectedException` annotation.

Comment: This is an exception due to symfony behavior, not a real one. Is it possible to avoid this behavior on defined environment (for my case, only on test env)